# python easy_install: specify directory housing required files

Tags: python, header-files, easy-install, mysql-python

I'm trying to use easy_install to install MySQL-python.  It fails almost immediately:

> _mysql.c:36:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
>   _mysql.c:38:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
>   _mysql.c:39:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
>   _mysql.c:40:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory

It can't find the headers.  I have the headers installed, they're just installed from source in /opt.  It's obviously not looking there.  How do I make it look there?  For example, if this was configure, I could do something like "--with-mysql=/opt/mysql".  It doesn't appear there is such an option with easy_install.  Still researching so if I find my answer I'll post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks more like an issue with the compiler search path than a easy_install issu.

Setting the include path environment variable before the easy_install call may work.

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/your/mysql/include/files easy_install intall MySQL-python
```

If that doesn't work, try setting the INCLUDE_PATH or CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH variables.  There wasn't enough easy_install output in the question to tell what compiler is being used.

Comment: I wonder why easy_install/pip don't honor my INCLUDE_PATH env var.  Thanks for the post.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Instead I was able to get past the error by installing pkg-config (sudo apt-get install pkg-config)

Answer (score 3):

`easy_install` invokes `setup.py`, which will respect a `setup.cfg` file in the distribution it's trying to install. Although you cannot specify the setup.py options `--include_dirs` and `--library_dirs` directly to easy_install, you can put them in the setup.cfg file.

I have a similar issue with pysqlite: I put SQLite in a non-standard location, and wanted to use easy_install to get the Python bindings. The pysqlite distribution includes a setup.cfg file with sample include_dirs and library_dirs directives, so it was clear what to do.

If MySQL-python has a setup.cfg file, you could try adding / editing it to include:

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs = /path/to/headers
library_dirs = /path/to/libs
```

If there's already a `[build_ext]` section in the setup.cfg file, add to it instead of creating a second one.