# Understanding concepts of Python installation on Mac OS for Cocoa development

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, cocoa-bindings, py2app

I want to try to develop Cocoa application using Python. I'm new to Mac and I need some help to understand how it works.

First of all I found that I need to install py2app and py2objc. I used easy_install as documented [here](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html). There were a few errors with setup tools but eventually py2app was installed. Then I launch "`easy_install pyobjc==2.2`" and it ended with many errors:

```
Processing pyobjc-2.2-py2.7.egg
    ...
Running pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration-2.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ipMzFU/pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration-2.2/egg-dist-tmp-odfVol
    In file included from Modules/_manual.m:1:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:20: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:22:2: error: #error "Something's broken.  UCHAR_MAX should be defined in limits.h."
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:26:2: error: #error "Python's source code assumes C's unsigned char is an 8-bit type."
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:35:5: error: #error "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL."
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:38:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:40:19: error: errno.h: No such file or directory
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:42:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:44:20: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:56:20: error: assert.h: No such file or directory
...
etc
```

My questions:

1. What I need to do to install
   py2objc? Unfortunately, I haven't
   found a solution for errors, which I
   posted previously.
2. As I understand
       there are two kinds of python. One I
       installed into Applications folder
       (IDLE, launcher), another is the
       current Python version supplied with
       OS. Can you describe the
       difference?
3. How can I select the
       current version of Python used by
       Mac OS? And what is the Current
       folder in
       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework?

Probably it looks confusing, but this is my first steps! :)
Thank you

Comment: Looks like some include files cannot be found. Which means the include-dir is set wrong. See this question on how to specify the include dir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753127
The missing include files live in `/usr/include`

Answer (score 1):

1. Cannot give a definitive answer to that. See comment.
2. You can install multiple versions of python on your machine (OSX includes a defualt one as you already mentioned). In the applications folder there are some apps to open an interactive interpreter in which you can enter python commands, such as IDLE. These applications use one of the python versions you've got installed. Which brings us to
3. `python_select` is the command you want. e.g. `python_select -l` to list all the python versions you've got installed and `python_select python27` to select your own 2.7 version. The `Current` folder links to the version currently selected via `python_select`

Comment: That's strange! I received: "bash: python_select: command not found"

Comment: I installed Macports and python_select package. I also reinstalled XCode cause I need "Unix dev tools" for Macports. I think it also changed python configuration because 'python_select -l' outputs that I have only one version of Python: 2.6. I need a time to figure out :))